# Finding $\liminf$ and $\limsup$

Tags: analysis

> $x_n := \frac {(n+3)(-1)^n}{n}$ Find $\limsup$, $\liminf$

Attempt:

$x_{2n} = \frac {2n+3}{2n} = 1$ as $n\to \infty$

Therefore $\limsup = 1$

$x_{2n+1} = -\frac {2n+4}{2n+1} = -1$ as $n\to \infty$

Therefore $\liminf = -1$

Is this correct/sufficient in answering the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much more easy, just take a look at $(-1)^n$:
$$
n = 2m \Rightarrow (-1)^n=1
$$
$$
n=2m+1 \Rightarrow (-1)^n=-1
$$

So,

$$
\limsup = \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n+3}{n}=1
$$
$$
\liminf = \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{-n-3}{n}=-1
$$

Comment: Although your way may be easier, is the approach I took still technically correct?

Comment: @Sky yes, it is totally correct, don't worry about it